How to Extracting Only Date and Amount from the Reference

I have a Column with reference information with date values and the amount; I need to extract only the Date and the Amount, A single reference Pattern Like below:
SIInv:HI-24-SIN-SOH-00948 Date: 12 Mar 2024 Due Date: 04 Jul 2024 Amt: 50.00
The same reference text is added multiple times in a single row. I need to extract only the date values and the amount in an individual column.


Select the column 2. Click on Data |Text To columns | Fixed Width. Remove unwanted arrows and split your data in multiple columns and then keep the text that you want?


It’s quite difficult since I have similar references repeating more than 10 times in some rows. I am looking for a dynamic formula method to extract the date and amount

Try this for date =DATEVALUE(MID(A1, FIND("Date:", A1) + 6, 11)) and =VALUE(TRIM(MID(A1, FIND("Amt:", A1) + 5, 10))) for amount. I am assuming that the text is in A1.

And yes, format the cell as date as datevalue will return date as number in a general formatted cell. I am off to bed. If you have any query, I will try and answer tomorrow i.e. if no one else answered it.

Assumptions:

Data in A1
Reference may include multiple sequences of {SIInv:,Date:,Due Date:,Amt:}
You want the results in the same row and order (except for SIInv).

If you have 365, the following will work:
=LET(
    ref, FILTERXML(
        "<t><s>" &
            REDUCE(
                SUBSTITUTE(A1, ",", ""),
                {"SIInv:", "Due Date:", "Date:", "Amt:"},
                LAMBDA(a, b, SUBSTITUTE(a, b, "</s><s>"))
            ) & "</s></t>",
        "//s[position()>1]"
    ),
    datesAmts, TOROW(
        MAKEARRAY(
            ROWS(ref),
            1,
            LAMBDA(r, c, IF(OR(r = SEQUENCE(ROWS(ref) / 4, , 1, 4)), NA(), CHOOSEROWS(ref, r)))
        ),
        2
    ),
    res, MAKEARRAY(
        1,
        COLUMNS(datesAmts),
        LAMBDA(r, c,
            IF(
                MOD(c, 3) = 0,
                TEXT(CHOOSECOLS(datesAmts, c), "$0.00"),
                TEXT(CHOOSECOLS(datesAmts, c), "dd mmm yyyy")
            )
        )
    ),
    res
)



Thank you so much. It works well, but if the pattern repeats, the amount adds a comma at the end. Any amendment in the formula, also can't we convert this formula into single array?

@MohamedRizmi Just remove the comma from the initial string. Since you chose to not post a textual version of your repeated References I had no way of knowing about the comma. I have edited my answer to show that addition. And the formula does produce an array for each Reference, as you must have seen when you tried it.

Assuming your data row is cell B3, the date value can be extracted with:
=DATEVALUE(TRIM(TEXTBEFORE(TEXTAFTER(TOCOL(TEXTSPLIT(B3,",")),"DueDate:"),"Amt:")))

and then you can format the cell as a date.
and the Amount can be extracted with:
=TEXTAFTER(TOCOL(TEXTSPLIT(B3,",")),"Amt:")*1

